# how to avoid crawling shared disk without bring it down?

Tags: nutch

I am using Nutch. I plan to crawl shared disk instead of internet website.

One thing I am worry is that crawling it will make that disk become really slow.
how to avoid crawling shared disk without bring it down?

Answer (score 1):

You can set the number of threads and wait time between requests in conf/nutch-site.xml.

Try overrinding these properties and set them to a value that you feel comfortable with:

```
<property>
  <name>fetcher.threads.fetch</name>
  <value>10</value>
  <description>The number of FetcherThreads the fetcher should use.
  This is also determines the maximum number of requests that are
  made at once (each FetcherThread handles one connection). The total
  number of threads running in distributed mode will be the number of
  fetcher threads * number of nodes as fetcher has one map task per node.
  </description>
</property>

<property>
  <name>fetcher.threads.per.queue</name>
  <value>1</value>
  <description>This number is the maximum number of threads that
    should be allowed to access a queue at one time.
   </description>
</property>
```